# Spring Boot jpa - OneToMany multiple relationship with same entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, one-to-many

[This is example for multiple field relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000132/spring-jpa-multiple-relations-with-same-entity) but i want a entity relation with multiple entity with ManyToOne like below scenario.

I want to design a web site like stackoverflow.

so right now i found 3 entities

1. Question
2. Answer
3. Comment

I designed each entity as

**Comment**

```
public class Comment {
   private int commentId;
   private String content;
}
```

**Answer**

```
public class Answer {
   private int answerId;
   private String content;
   @OneToMany
   private List<Comment> comments;
}
```

**Question**

```
public class Question {
   private int questionId;
   private String content;
   @OneToMany
   private List<Comment> comments;
   @OneToMany
   private List<Answer> answers;
}
```

here `Comment` entity referred in both `Answer` and `Question` so how to configure relationship?

I have an idea with ManyToOne or OneToMany([Example1](https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/), [example2](https://www.javainterviewpoint.com/spring-data-jpa-one-to-many/)) with single entity relationship

Comment: You're going have to decide whether you a) want two comments tables - one for answers and one for questions or b) what a single comments table with two join tables.

Comment: I would like to go with option b.

Comment: @BoristheSpider why would he have to do that? An answer has many comments, a comment belongs to 0 or one answer. So it's a OneToMany, not a ManyToMany. Same for question-comment. A second OneToMany works exactly like a first OneToMany.

Comment: @JBNizet - isn't the easiest way to get Hibernate to create join tables just to use `@ManyToMany`? I imagine you can faff around with `@JoinTable` too. Because we want to end up with one COMMENT table and two ENTITY_X_COMMENT join tables.

Comment: No. A unidirectional OneToMany is mapped by a join table by default. If it's bidirectional, the correct way to use a join table instead of a join column is to use the JoinTable annotation. Not to cheat by pretending it's a ManyToMany. BTW, it generates a unique constraint for a OneToMany.

Comment: Fair enough - so the answer is in fact do nothing, it will just work!

Comment: Exactly. Absolutely. Yes.

Comment: Then isn't required have @ManyToOne in Comment entity?

Comment: No. That would make the association bidirectional. Here's the documentation about associations: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many

Comment: @JBNizet - A `ManyToOne` maps the association as Unidirectional. The `@OneToMany` maps a relationship as bidirectional. `@JoinTable` annotations don't specifically determine that. Typically `@ManyToOne` field is the owner of the association and the `mappedBy` annotation on the `@OneToMany` also indicates that. The `@JoinTable` annotation typically is just used to override default values. It might be able to reverse ownership of the association but I haven't tested that extensively as that would be unusual.

Comment: No. Not at all. A ManyToOne can be unidirectional. A OneToMany can be unidirectional. If an entity A has an association to an entity B, and the association also goes in the other direction, then it is bidirectional (that's plain English: the association goes in both directions, hence the term "bi-directional"). JoinTable specifies that the association is mapped... using a join table. Your terminology is wrong.

Comment: No, it's not anywhere near that simple, and please don't talk down to people. The normal way of doing a one-to-many is to use a foreign key. A join table should only be used for many-to-many relations. Granted, Hibernate, at least,  uses a join table by 'default' for a one-to-many annotation but you should be starting with a many-to-one annotation to create your foreign key in the child table then use mappedBy if you insist on having a one-to-many in the parent. You don't need a one-to-many and your code will be better without it and you won't have lazy exceptions.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, is there also option C? To have one comment table and single relation table? And this single join table will store relation to both: Question and Answer. It will has columns:
(id),
comment_id: Comment,
question_id: Question?,
answer_id: Answer?